# Django-forms code is giving all of my forms ViewDoesNotExist errors

Tags: django, django-forms

This piece of code for some reason is causing `ViewDoesNotExist` errors for many of my templates:

```
CHOICES = list ( (obj.manufacturer,obj.manufacturer) for obj in UniPart.objects.all().values('manufacturer').distinct() )
```

When I comment out that code and substitute with hard-coded choices, all is fine.

What the heck is happening?

Here is how I use it in my `forms.py`:

```
CHOICES = list ( (obj.manuacturer,obj.manufacturer) for obj in UniPart.objects.all().values('manufacturer').distinct() )
manufacturer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

UniPart is defined as follows:

```
class UniPart (models.Model):
    manufacturer=models.CharField(_('manufacturer'), max_length=255)
```

Here's the `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^add$','mysims.views.add_model'),
```

And the `mysims` app `views.py`:

```
def add_model(request, points=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        formtoaddmodel = newsimform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        new_sim = formtoaddmodel.save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Show us the urls.py, the views.py and the whole form.

Comment: Ok added it. I've been using this form properly for months now. It's that one line of code that has changed causing the problem.

Comment: 1) the `CHOICES` here is a bug since it is defined at the class level. This means it will be read *once*. when the server starts. So when you'll create more `UniPart` instances, the choices won't be updated. 2) So `views.product_feed` comes out of nowhere? It doesn't ring a bell or something?

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong screenshot but same error: `Could not import mysims.views.add_model. View does not exist in module mysims.views.`

Comment: What is a better implementation then to get updated UniPart instances?

Comment: Do you use the `get_absolute_url` or permalink on your model?

Comment: Correct implementation would be to populate the choices inside the `__init__` method of your form. If you search some of my recent answers here, I have many such examples.

Comment: One field in my model is an image field that uploads to Amazon S3. Otherwise every field in the model is a text/character field.

Comment: I was talking about this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url

Comment: Do you use the `reverse` function for the views? Any mysterious `__unicode__` method on your model?

Comment: Nope there's not of that either

Comment: Well I give up for now since I don't have the whole picture and I'm out of assumptions :)

Comment: Actually there's one reverse statement after submitting the form in the view. `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("mysims.views.your_models"))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19563/discussion-between-rantanplan-and-user1328021)